# Change tabs bar height

Tags: css, ionic-framework

What is the best way of modifying the height of the tabs bar (see below)? Whilst making sure that no overlaps with nav bars and content occur and that the tab items are vertically centered.

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only">

  <ion-tab title="Home" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
    <!-- Tab 1 content -->
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="About" icon-on="ion-ios-clock" icon-off="ion-ios-clock-outline">
    <!-- Tab 2 content -->
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Settings" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline">
    <!-- Tab 3 content -->
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

After more researching I think I found a way by overwriting the variables in _variables.scss.

My **custom sass file** look like this, and is overwriting the value in _variables.scss.

```
$tabs-height:                     49px !default;

// Include all of Ionic
@import "www/lib/ionic/scss/ionic";
```

Comment: I directly changed `$tabs-height` in _variable.scss but it didnt reflect.